# Switching JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Now, I have a frame setup like this

```
[]Form MainApplet  
|  
----[]Other Components  
|    |  
|    +--jFrame2  
|   
+ -- jFrame
```

On load it runs [JFrame1], the one at the bottom, I want it then to change to jFrame2? How can I do this? I have tried various pieces of code, and example would be helpful! Thanks,

Comment: No, this is different, Launching of Applet fails was about two classes, this is within the same class. Look, please Hovercraft Full of Eels, can you help?

Comment: What do you mean by change? Is the second frame already open?

Comment: No, it isn't, I have it as a component of the original frame, and wish it to run? I just don't know how to get it to run?

Comment: What do you mean by "run"?  Do you just want to open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I take it, you have multiple frames open, and you just want to change the focus. This is easily achieved like so `jFrame2.requestFocus()` if you want your second JFrame to become the selected one.

Comment: This does not make a Window into a top-level window. Rather this method (or better `requestFocusInWindow()`) is called on a *Component* and makes that component the focused component in the window, *if* the component is focusable. So in short, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Thanks TheNerdyCoder for some real help!